# highcharts v3.0Beta bubblechart not rendering. Possible bug?

Tags: highcharts

I've get a problem using a bubble chart and specifying min and max values on the x axis. In this example, no points are plotted:

```
   $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts bubbles problem'
    },               
    xAxis: {
        min:20,
        max:80
    },
    yAxis: {       
        min:-80,
        max:80
    },
    series: [{ 
        data: [ {"x":23,"y":22,"z":200}, {"x":43,"y":12,"z":100} ]
    }]
});
```

As you can see in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Qhh3/, the chart doesn't plot any bubbles.

If you remove the min parameter from the x axis, it works If you change it to a scatter chart, it also works. It only seems to fail if it's a bubble chart AND you specify a min on the xAxis.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in v3.0Beta?

UPDATE: I am getting a console error: 'radii is undefined' on line 1905 of highcharts-more.js

UPDATE: I've emailed this to highcharts support.

UPDATE: Confirmed as a bug by highcharts support.

Comment: It's not the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a bug, so I've reported it to our devs https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1578

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed as a bug in v3.0Beta by highcharts support.