# Highcharts can't render a bubble chart with a single series

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I'm using the new bubble chart included in Highcharts 3.0 Beta and I'm facing a strange bug : when I try to render a bubble chart with only one series of data, it doesn't display anything... and doesn't throw any error. Here's the code (or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keX3M/))

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts bubbles bug'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [{
            "x": 23,
            "y": 22,
            "z": 200
        }]
    }]

});
});
```

Something similar was signalled here : [highcharts v3.0Beta bubblechart not rendering. Possible bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275162/highcharts-v3-0beta-bubblechart-not-rendering-possible-bug) (and it has been confirmed as a bug), but I'm not using min and max values for X nor Y axis, and I only pass a single bubble in a single series.

So, is this a bug, or is it a normal behaviour (and if so, why ?) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be related to the other bug. If you add:

```
    xAxis: { max:50
           },
    yAxis: {min:0, max:50},
```

to your jsfiddle, it starts working.

Even adding:

```
yAxis: {max:30},
```

makes it plot the bubble.

The original bug I reported was fixed yesterday in github, so you could try out the new version from there if you want to. https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/js